# php dropdown selection Inserts only the first word in the table

Tags: php, mysql

```
<center><?php
            include "config.php"; // Database connection using PDO

            //$sql="SELECT name,id FROM student"; 

            $sql="SELECT Product_Name, id FROM stockcount"; 

            /* You can add order by clause to the sql statement if the names are to be displayed in alphabetical order */
            ?>
            <select id = 'ProductName' name='productName' onchange="" >Product_Name </option>"
            <?php
            foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row

                echo "<option value=$row[Product_Name]>$row[Product_Name
                ]</option>"; 

                /* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 

            }
              ?>
             </select>
             </center><p></P>
```

This code shows all the product names from the stockcount table.

```
<?PHP

include ('config.php');

$date = $_POST['date'];
$productname = $_POST['productName'];
$cartons = $_POST['cartons'];
$send_to = $_POST['send_To'];



$sql = "INSERT INTO storerequest (Date, Product_Name, Cartons, Send_To) VALUES ('$date','$productname', '$cartons', '$send_to')";


if ($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {

        header("Location:orderrequest.php");
}

else {

    echo "Error is " .$sql."<br>". $conn->error;

}

$conn->close();

?>
```

This adds the selection from the dropdown to the storerequest table.

Now the problem is if i select an option named "Motor Car" from the down. It inserts in the storerequest table as "Motor" only. When i changed the product name to "Motor-Car" then it inserts as "Motor-Car". It basically stores only the 1st word. Please experts help me solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `"` signs for the `value`:

```
 echo '<option value="'.$row[Product_Name].'">'.$row[Product_Name].'</option>"';
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

need to change `echo` statement.
Change From

```
echo "<option value=$row[Product_Name]>$row[Product_Name]</option>";
```

To

```
echo "<option value='$row[Product_Name]'>$row[Product_Name]</option>";
```

Comment: @RhinoDevel actually there are no laws about using attribute values in only double quotes, they can in fact use either single or double quoted values or not be quotes at all, depending on a few rules. [See the manual](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html)

Comment: @RiggsFolly You're right! Sorry and thanks (but it is very uncommon, isn't it?).

Comment: Uncommon, yes, I always us `"` but its not a law.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or if you need the double quotes for html just escape them : 
`echo "$row[Product_Name]";

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not wrapping the value of your `value` attribute in either single or double quotes.

i.e. `value=$row[Product_Name]`

```
echo "<option value=$row[Product_Name]>$row[Product_Name]</option>";
```

You dont have to wrap the attributes value in quotes, BUT YOU DO if the value has a space in it like `Motor Car`

So you must do

```
echo "<option value='$row[Product_Name]'>$row[Product_Name]</option>";
```

Or

```
echo '<option value="' . $row['Product_Name'] . '">' . $row['Product_Name'] . '</option>';
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly :)